# wordpress absolute div does not stack in front of header

Tags: css, wordpress, css-position

Ok, so I don't know what exactly happens in this wordpress page, I cannot put it into generic terms...I expected this absolute div should stay above the header. I tried with z-index, overflow:visible...Nothing, it stacks behind the header (which has a div with a fixed height of 300px).Is it because of wordpress?
The link here: http://lianavoinea.opa.ro/stacking-problem/

```
<header></header>
<div style="
position:absolute;
background:red;
width:300px;
height:200px;
top:-100px;">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec pharetra sit amet quam sit amet facilisis. Phasellus efficitur congue mi, non mattis orci ultrices in. Maecenas fringilla, mauris vel gravida eleifend, neque dolor iaculis enim, in aliquet arcu magna ut purus. Suspendisse risus sem, placerat at tortor ac, volutpat sagittis orci. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis
 </div>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your absolute-positioned `div` is "clipped" on the bounding rectangle of its parent (`top:-100px`).

The solution is to specify `overflow: visible` on the container div. 
In your case:

```
.content {
    /* ... */
    overflow: visible;
}
```

Comment: thanks, I had put overflow visible to other layers but not this one, great!